# How to install gettext from source if msgfmt doesn't have the option --desktop?

Tags: software-installation, gettext

I need to upgrade `gettext` on the travis-ci.org CI service which is based on Ubuntu 14.04 because of `The AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION declaration in your configure.ac file requires the infrastructure from gettext-0.19 but this version is older. Please upgrade to gettext-0.19 or newer`, so I'm doing that by running `wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.19.8.1.tar.xz && tar xf gettext-0.19.8.1.tar.xz && ./configure && make -j && sudo make install && cd ..`, but that fails due to `/usr/bin/msgfmt: unrecognized option '--desktop'`. Since `msgfmt` is provided by `gettext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

- remove the existing `msgfmt` binary, either `sudo apt-get remove gettext` and check that there're no others in the `/usr/local` or other prefixes
- install `gettext` from source with the default `./configure && make && sudo make install`